# how can i use timestamp/Datetime with EF and blazor?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, blazor

I'm working on project using for database sql server ,entity framework and Swagger and for backend c# using Blazor framework .
For business reasons , one of compsite key is must "datetime" , whatever it's datatype timestamp or datetime .
while in database i tryed to make this field to be any related datetime types such as (DateTime, Date and Timestamp) and have issues.

when i made the field data type in database as followed :

1- **DateTime** so EF scaffolding into model class as DateTime , but get error message that can not accept the datetime format from the user {6/21/2023 12:08:10 PM} to server accepted format {yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}.

2- **Timestamp** EF scaffolding it into model class as  **byte[]** and when using this field (salesMenComm.SalesFromDate) in blazor's inputDate form field, it does not accepted as it waits DateTime:

*<InputDate id="SalesFromDate" @bind-Value="salesMenComm.SalesFromDate" class="form-control" required>*

so, error message is internal server error and status code :500

Comment: `timestamp` *isn't* a date and time value, it's a `binary(8)`; it has *nothing* to do with times. It's a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`. Don't try to store a date (and time) in a `timestamp`, it won't work.

Comment: `timestamp` is the ancient (pre-2005) name of the `rowversion` type. A `datetime` or `datetime2` already has a time component and both are mapped to DateTime.  Time-of-day is represented by `time`, date-only by `date`. These are mapped to TimeOnly and DateOnly

Comment: timestamp may be 'ancient', it is still the name of the attibute used in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.  @ahmedantar : make sure whether _one of compsite key is must "datetime"_ is about DateTime or RowVersion. Although RowVersion in a key is uncommon.

Comment: *"Although RowVersion in a key is uncommon."* I'd suggest a *terrible* idea. it would mean you could *never* `UPDATE` that row as doing so would cause the value of the `rowversion` to change and thus any values in a table that sues that key as a foreign key would need updating too. It would be a nightmare.

Comment: @ThomA - yes, i think you're right. I was probably thinking of some other construct with DateTime.

Comment: @Thom A 
Thanks for your effort and replay.
i agree that is not common , but i've to as business needs in work you know!!
what i'm traing to achieve is to make a unique value of datetime in every entery i make in database so, i can search with it to get results

Comment: And a `timestamp` **does not** do that, it has *nothing* to do with dates and times...

Comment: I would urge you to rethink trying to make every datetime value in your database be unique. That just screams of a design that went the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Lange ,
Not every datetime values are unique !, that's the only one field that i would be datetime to search with time .